# What are the red circles that move across the map?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am new to the game and when watching on twitch I sometimes see these red circles moving across the screen. What are they, I tried googling.

[image]

Comment: What part of Summoners' Rift is this?

Comment: its near red buff on the red side of the map. You can see it in this clip. https://clips.twitch.tv/MotionlessApatheticAniseAMPTropPunch

Comment: @James24 To be clear, it is the red circle at 12s and is only on the screen for .5s?

Comment: yes thats the one, its not near his cursor what does it mean? is it a teammates clicking, or something to do with a spell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the indicator for where you will land if you activate the Blast Cone jungle plant you are standing near.